# Flatness and Cohen-Macaulay rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, cohen-macaulay

Let $A$ be a local Artin ring, $R$ a local Noetherian ring, $f:A \to R$ a flat morphism and $R$ is cohen-Macaulay. Let $I$ be an ideal in $R$ such that $R/I$ is also Cohen-Macaulay. Under what condition on $R/I$ can we conclude that $R/I$ is flat over $A$ i.e., the composition $A \to R \to R/I$ is flat? Recall that the answer to this question is well-known in the case $A$ is regular.

Comment: And what's the answer for the regular case?

Comment: This is a result in Eisenbud's book on commutative algebra wih a view towards algebraic geometry (Theorem 18.16 in the version that I have) which says that if $R/I$ is CM, then it is flat over $A$ if and only if $\dim R/I=\dim A+\dim R/(m_AR)$, where $m_A$ is the maximal ideal of $A$ (under the assumption that $A$ is regular).